# Microsoft Access 2013 'Conditional Format' a graph based on vertical axis

Tags: ms-access, graph, bar-chart, conditional-formatting

I am trying to get my graph to be color coded based on the type of Project (SRSH, SRCA, etc.).  The ones that begin with S are together, as the ones with H and I are together separately.  Is there a way to 'Conditionally format' - these data bars to be a different color based on their category?

Thanks in advance,

[Picture of what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRi9y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim g As Object
Set g = Forms!MyForm!MyGraph.Object
If g.SeriesCollection.Count > 0 Then
  g.SeriesCollection("SRSH").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End If
Set g = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code will change the color of the "SRSH" series on the graph. Simply add lines in the `IF` block to color the other series.

This is static code, so if the structure of the chart changes you will need to adapt the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response; however,This database will be continuously updated and therefore in need of a more dynamic solution.

Comment: @Dhill Ok, this is the beginning of the dynamic solution. Are you comfortable with VBA? You simply need to use parameters to capture the series names, and then place the parameter where the "SRSH" is. Will the count of series change?

Comment: I have used VBA before, but whenever I try to incorporate it into access, it does not seem to work..

Comment: Try checking out [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181598) link. It's based on Northwind, but illustrates how to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.